# How to increase sound volume on eMac P69 running FreeBSD 10.3?

Tags: freebsd, audio, macintosh

I've got FreeBSD 10.3 (PowerPC) installed on eMac P69.

I'm using MPlayer to test loudness. I already use `-af volume=10:1`-like options but they tend to distort sound pretty quickly + it is not really a solution.

From what I read online I should be able to change volume using `systcl hw.snd.vpc_0db` or `mixer(8)`. Unfortunately:

- `systcl hw.snd.vpc_0d=45` is too quiet
- `systcl hw.snd.vpc_0d=10` is quite ok but still it could/should go louder
- `systcl hw.snd.vpc_0d=1` is distorted and really not that louder than `10`
- `mixer` returns:

  > mixer: /dev/mixer: No such file or directory

From what I remember when this machine still had Mac OS X its speakers were way louder comparing to what I get on FreeBSD.

#### Questions

1. Why is `/dev/mixer` missing?
2. Is there any other way to increase speaker volume?

#### Other details

They might come in handy:

- */boot/loader.conf*

  ```
  sound_load="YES"
  snd_driver_load="YES"
  ```
- I tried `kldload snd_hda` but it didn't help.
- `kldload snd_driver` results in

  > kldload: can't load snd_driver: No such file or directory

  Also, there are interesting messages in the system message buffer displayed with `dmesg`:

  > link_elf: symbol isa_dma_release undefined
  >    KLD snd_driver.ko: depends on snd_sb8 - not available or version mismatch

Comment: I think you're just using the wrong driver.

Comment: @SKull, maybe, but what's the correct one then?

Comment: I have no idea what an eMac 69 is. Look up its specs and see if you find the chip. man snd_driver should contain a comprehensive list of all the drivers. snd_driver is just the 'general' one for common chips

Comment: Also post the output of 'cat /dev/sndstat'